# Extracting a common interface for Stacks and Queues

Tags: polymorphism, ocaml, functor

I'm would like to compare the performance of two heuristics for a game AI that I am working on. One processes elements in FIFO order; the other in LIFO order.

As it stands, the code uses a `Queue` to process element in FIFO order. In OOP I would have a `Bag` interface implemented by both `Stack` and `Queue`, and I would use `Bag.push` and `Bag.take` to interact with the structure. Then I would assign the result of either `Stack.create ()` or `Queue.create ()` to a variable of type `Bag`, based on the value of a command line flag, for example.

I know how to replicate similar behavior in OCaml using abstract classes and constraining types with `:>`. However, I imagine that there might be a cleaner way to do this, that wouldn't require writing wrapper classes around `Queue` and `Stack`.

I tried something like

```
module type Bag =
sig
    type 'a t
    exception Empty
    val create : unit -> 'a t
    val push : 'a -> 'a t -> unit
    val iter : ('a -> unit) -> 'a t -> unit
end

module BagWrapper (B : Bag) = 
struct
    type 'a t = 'a B.t
    let create () = B.create ()
    let push a b = B.push a b
    let iter a b = B.iter a b
end 

module QueueBag = BagWrapper(Queue)
module StackBag = BagWrapper(Stack)
```

...but I'm not sure what to do next. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ygrek solution using first-class modules to decide "dynamically"
(on a boolean value) the value of the `Bag` module is fine, but you can also do
that in simpler OCaml by simply defining your traversal algorithm
inside a functor taking a bag as parameter.

```
module type Bag =
sig
    type 'a t
    exception Empty
    val create : unit -> 'a t
    val push : 'a -> 'a t -> unit
    val pop : 'a t -> 'a
    val iter : ('a -> unit) -> 'a t -> unit
end

module Traversal (B : Bag) = struct
  let go start children f =
    let to_visit = B.create () in
    B.push start to_visit;
    try while true do
      let next = B.pop to_visit in
      f next;
      let mark neighbor = B.push neighbor to_visit in
      List.iter mark (children next);
    done with B.Empty -> ()
end;;

(* note that "BagWrapper" is useless here as the existing modules
   fit the Bag interface perfectly, there is no need for a middle
   layer *)
module StackTraversal = Traversal(Stack)
module QueueTraversal = Traversal(Queue)


(* ... if foo then StackTraversal.go else QueueTraversal.go ... *)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's neat as well!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so you want to write

```
let module Bag = if use_queue then QueueBag else StackBag in
some algorithm
```

but OCaml won't let you do it..

[First-class modules](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual021.html#toc81) to the rescue!

```
let m = if use_queue then (module QueueBag : Bag) else (module StackBag : Bag) in
let module Bag = (val m : Bag) in
```

This looks rather verbose, fortunately newer OCaml versions let you drop some type annotations in this case.